# Selenium remote webdriver not accepting chrome options in Synology Nas. Works fine on desktop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

Changing from windows to synology has broken my docker compose.
The chrome options are now not being listened to buy the selenium container.
The downloads location has changed and is asking for download confirmation.

I have build a python app to log in an download a report. 
I have dockerise it with two seperate containers. A selenuim standalone chrome broswer and ptyhon 3 image. It works fine on my windows 10 PC.

But when i set it up on my DS918+ the chrome some of the chrome options are not being listened to in the chrome container. 
If i use the debug i can vnc in and manually confirm and it does download fine.

any help with the Chrome options would be Appreciated?

Compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
    pythoncode:
        build: ./app
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app

        networks:
            testing_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1
        environment: 
            - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
            - EmailUser=
            - EmailSender=
            - EmailPass=
            - NZCUser=
            - NZCPass=

    browser:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug

        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
            - "5900:5900"
        volumes:
            - ./app/Downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads
        depends_on: 
            - pythoncode
        networks:
            testing_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2

networks:
    testing_net:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

python options

```
capabilities_chrome = {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        # 'proxy': { \
        # 'proxyType': 'manual',
        # 'sslProxy': '50.59.162.78:8088',
        # 'httpProxy': '50.59.162.78:8088'
        # },
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            'args': [
            ],
            'prefs': { \
                # 'download.default_directory': "",
                # 'download.directory_upgrade': True,
                'download.prompt_for_download': False,
                'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True,
                'safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled': False
            }
        }
    }

    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    #     executable_path=, desired_capabilities=capabilities_chrome)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        'http://172.28.1.2:4444/wd/hub', capabilities_chrome)
```

selenuim debug report

```
2020-03-17 17:01:08,955 INFO stopped: xvfb (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-03-17 17:01:08,954 INFO stopped: fluxbox (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-03-17 17:01:08,951 INFO stopped: vnc (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-03-17 17:01:08,950 INFO stopped: selenium-standalone (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-03-17 17:01:08,949 INFO waiting for xvfb, selenium-standalone, vnc, fluxbox to die
2020-03-17 17:01:08,949 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
Trapped SIGTERM/SIGINT/x so shutting down supervisord...
17:01:03.576 INFO [ActiveSessions$1.onStop] - Removing session f885300040124a841b3627e1fdf57233 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
[1584464415.350][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1584464415.248][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1584464415.146][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1584464414.961][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
17:00:14.392 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session f885300040124a841b3627e1fdf57233 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
17:00:14.338 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: W3C
[1584464411.379][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 2548
17:00:11.227 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
}
  }
    }
      "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": false
      "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": true,
      "download.prompt_for_download": false,
    "prefs": {
    ],
    "args": [
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
  "browserName": "chrome",
17:00:11.223 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
17:00:10.515 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
17:00:10.317 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
2020-03-17 17:00:09.747:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1154ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
17:00:09.634 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
17:00:09.306 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
2020-03-17 17:00:09,298 INFO success: selenium-standalone entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-17 17:00:09,298 INFO success: vnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-17 17:00:09,298 INFO success: fluxbox entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-17 17:00:09,298 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-17 17:00:08,296 INFO spawned: 'selenium-standalone' with pid 14
2020-03-17 17:00:08,294 INFO spawned: 'vnc' with pid 13
2020-03-17 17:00:08,292 INFO spawned: 'fluxbox' with pid 12
2020-03-17 17:00:08,290 INFO spawned: 'xvfb' with pid 11
2020-03-17 17:00:07,287 INFO supervisord started with pid 8
2020-03-17 17:00:07,283 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium.conf" during parsing
2020-03-17 17:00:07,283 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium-debug.conf" during parsing
```